# Reading a file in C with input with different data types

Tags: c, fgets, fread, scanf

I am reading a file in C that is formatted like this

```
int int int int char double double
```

but repeated a known number of times. (The first line of the file, not listed in the sample, specifies the number of times this sequence will repeat) I want to parse these values into a structure. However, I am not sure how to read these elements as they have different datatypes, 
I was looking at three different methods

fread --> does not work because the different elements are of different data types and wont have the same number of bytes.

fscanf --> does not work because of multiple different data types

fgets--> does not work becase it only stops once there is a newline character.

So I am not sure what to do about this. Maybe I am looking to hard for an elegant solution to loading a file with ugly input like this, or maybe I am overlooking something in one of the functions that I have already mentioned.

This is for a school project btw, but I am not asking for an answer, just a hint.

I am limited to what I can use in the stdio and the stdlib libraries.

thanks for all the help

Comment: I think the standard way is to use `fgets` and read each line into a local `char` array, and then using `sscanf` to read the individual pieces.

Comment: Thanks merlin, I think the fscanf method with multiple type specifiers seems to be the best/easiest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the earlier answers, you would need something like:

```
int intVar1;
int intVar2;
int intVar3;
int intVar4;
char c;
double doubleVar1;
double doubleVar2;

fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %c %lf %lf", 
       &intVar1,
       &intVar2,
       &intVar3,
       &intVar4,
       &c,
       &doubleVar1,
       &doubleVar2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` should work.

```
fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %c %lf %lf", ....);
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I was able to utilize fscanf in this way! I thought it could only read one thing at once and had to be iterated!  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: One last question, would all of these values be read into an array or would each get its own declared variable?

Comment: @Liquidmetal You can declare separate variables for them or read them into a struct or w/e you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any of those functions to read from the file. the easiest to use for this case is `fscanf()`
you can read inside a loop since you know the number of times to read by just iterating known number of times.

```
fscanf(fd,"%d %d %d %d %d %c %lf %lf",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,%f,&h)
```

or you can create a structure

```
struct data
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  char e;
  double h;
  double i;
}var1;
```

and use it in fscanf() to fill the value for its members

Comment: Thanks, the guy below this pointed out something that I didn't know that I was able to do.